# Set height of 2 div's via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, header, size, navbar

on my website I have a header (which is a background image) and under it a navbar. I like the header and navbar to fill 100% of the screen height.
If I change the height of the header to 80% or something like that it only works on certain desktops sizes. On bigger ones you can see the content area below the navbar or on smaller ones only part of the navbar.

I figured it should be possible to define the size of header and navbar together via JavaScript (header+navbar= height 100%). The problem is, that I have never really worked with JavaScript before and couldn't find a code that would do that.

Does someone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: This should be done in CSS

Comment: Try using vh in your CSS instead of %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use css and javascript like this for both your navbar and your header:

```
 @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.navbar  li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.navbar li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the navbar with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the navbar look good on small screens */
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.navbar.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.navbar.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.navbar.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.navbar.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

then use this script :

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("IdOfnavbar");
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "navbar";
    }
}
```

External source: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp

Comment: Thanks for your help! but I don't see where exactly it helps me to define navbar-height+header-height=screen size? The navbar itself works great in responsive  and the header is only viewable on desktop and hidden in very small screen sizes. 
Can you explain it to me a little bit more detailed?

Comment: You can adjust the style depending on the screen size using max-width or min-width so that whatever is the screen size you have already anticipated that in your css code.

Comment: there is a lot of documentations about media queries, I hope you'll find better answers here, here is an external source that my be very helpful :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1):

```js
// jQuery solution
// ---------------
/*$(function() {
  $(window).on('load resize', function() {
    // set header height minus nav height
    $('header').height($(this).height()-$('nav').height());
  });
});*/


// vanillaJS
// ---------
// calculate height of header
/*var calculateHeight = function() {
  document.querySelector('header').style.height = window.innerHeight- document.querySelector('nav').clientHeight+'px';
}

// add event listener to window
window.addEventListener('load', calculateHeight);
window.addEventListener('resize', calculateHeight);*/

$(function() {
  var $nav = $('nav'),
      $header = $('header'),
      $content = $('.content'),
      navOffsetTop = 0;

  $(window).on('load resize', function() {
    // set header height minus nav height
    $header.height($(this).height()-$nav.height());
    navOffsetTop = $nav.offset().top;
  });


  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= navOffsetTop) {
      if(!$nav.hasClass('fixed')) {
        $nav.addClass('fixed');
        $content.css({
          marginTop: $nav.height()
        })
      }
    } else {
      if($nav.hasClass('fixed')) {
        $nav.removeClass('fixed');
        $content.removeAttr('style')
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  background: url('https://unsplash.it/1200/1200');
  background-size: cover;
}
nav {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 60px;
}
nav.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .3s;
  background-color: #999;
}
.content {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 900px;
}
.content.scrolled {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <nav></nav>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati quae, aliquam autem incidunt delectus consequatur accusamus quibusdam adipisci facilis sapiente praesentium. Error quibusdam officiis perferendis, eius saepe hic dolores atque!
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! this works great in theory (and is exactly what I am looking for!), but somehow not with my project. The problem seems to be, that I am using an affix navbar (that stays on top when scrolling down). I tried to implent your code. But as a result I get the .affix-top (my affix navbar has a different color when scrolling and turns grey wehen fixed on top. but here it is fixed and red - the color it supposed to have when scrolling) as a fixed navbar on top and the header is missing. 
Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

I used the CSS solution with setting vh instead of % to the header and navbar. It's not the pretties solution (from a designers perspective), since on bigger screens it streches the navbar in an ugly way. 
I'm gonna try and read more about java script, but for now the vh height works!
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of any element using following statement.

```
document.getElementById('id').style.height = "100px";
```

You can use above piece of code and can add your logic and should execute the code on page load.